# Problema de unicode textarea no IE8 e MVC2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

Eu estou com problema em um campo textarea.

Eu tenho um campo textarea o cliente digita neste campo insere ç ã àèìáéí, no textarea perfeito, no js também esta ok, mas quando resgato no controller o campo do textarea, todos caracteres especial ficam com ?

Isso só acontece com IE8 , Chrome e firefox está ok.

alguém sabe como resolver isto?

Answer (score 0):

Verifique o "character set" tanto do servidor quanto da página que está sendo gerada. Eles devem ser o mesmo, por exemplo, utf8. Se não forem iguais você terá problemas.

Na sua página, por exemplo, você deve ter uma linha como esta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Ou se estiver usando windows, o teclado, ao abrir o IE pode estar setado para usar outro padrão.